# Regex to not allow String Start or End With Special Character and should not have consecutive special characters

Tags: regex, string, validation

I want to set a password in my application. Password should not start and end with special characters and special characters can be added between the string. It may have special characters, But it should not have consecutive special characters . Here i have the regular expression that should not allow user to not enter string's starting character and ending character with special characters .

```
var string='877sswere';
var a= RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9](.*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$/).test(string);
console.log(a);
```

so my requirement is

```
string='877sswere' -> Correct
string='@877sswere' -> In Correct
string='!877sswere^' -> In Correct
string='877sswere$' -> In Correct
string='8&*77sswere' -> In Correct
string='87#7ssw$er^e' -> Correct
string='877^sswere' -> Correct
```

So can any one suggest me to how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So `877^$%@sswere` is not allow

Comment: Quit restricting passwords, it provides for a bad UX. Restricted passwords leads to lazy, less-secure passwords.

Comment: Please don't use the the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when your question contains nothing about this plugin.  I also don't see any [tag:jquery] code here.

Comment: @ Sparky: Sorry , i will remove it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
/^[a-z0-9](?!.*?[^\na-z0-9]{2}).*?[a-z0-9]$/gmi
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rN9zT8/1)

Comment: It is not working for single character input like a. However its working great for more than 1 character input.Can you please suggest what to modify it to match a single character also.

Comment: Regex can be tweaked to allow 1 character inout also but having length of 1 for password is not very common.

Comment: @HimanshuSharma: To allow 1 char input use: `/^(?!.*[^\na-z0-9]{2})(?=.*[a-z0-9]$)[a-z0-9].*$/gim`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for saving my day ! Actually i am using this pattern for input validation where i needed to validate single char input also.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you! Could you help me to extend the '1 char input' version? I need a solution which allows only the -_ special characters. For example: this-is_valid, this!is~not?valid. Thanks a lot once more! [regex101.com/r/6kbdwR/1](https://regex101.com/r/6kbdwR/1)

Comment: @AndrásSzabácsik: Use `^(?!.*[-_]{2})(?=.*[a-z0-9]$)[a-z0-9][a-z0-9_-]*$` or see https://regex101.com/r/6kbdwR/2